# How to distinct (count), group by and sum data in DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
a = [{'order': '789', 'name': 'A', 'date': 20220501, 'sum': 15.1}, {'order': '456', 'name': 'A', 'date': 20220501, 'sum': 19}, {'order': '704', 'name': 'B', 'date': 20220502, 'sum': 14.1},  {'order': '704', 'name': 'B', 'date': 20220502, 'sum': 22.9}, {'order': '700', 'name': 'B', 'date': 20220502, 'sum': 30.1}, {'order': '710', 'name': 'B', 'date': 20220502, 'sum': 10.5}]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

print(df)
```

I need, to distinct (count) value in column `order` and to add values to the new  column `order_count`, grouping by columns `name` and `date`, sum values in column `sum`.

I need to get the next result:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and use three backticks to enclose preformatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case do

```
out = df.groupby(['name','date'],as_index=False).agg({'sum':'sum','order':'nunique'})
Out[652]: 
  name      date   sum  order
0    A  20220501  34.1      2
1    B  20220502  77.6      3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df[['name','date','sum']].groupby(by=['name','date']).sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'sum':'order_count'}).join(df[['name','date','sum']].groupby(by=['name','date']).count().reset_index().drop(['name','date'],axis=1))
```